# Share internet in Linux

Tags: linux, internet

I have an 3.5G USB Modem that I want to share its internet connection in Linux. I tried already, but only got having no internet on my own PC, still without sharing it.

It's really hard to find some documentation about this and the producer doesn't give support for Linux :(

My modem is from ZTE company, model MF622.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the best way to accomplish what you want is to route the connection to your PC through the linux system. Try this tutorial on the ubuntu community site. If this isn't what you wanted, comment.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing

Answer (score 1):

To enable internet connection sharing you first have to get your internet connection working and then set up masquerading (NAT).

See the [NAT HOWTO](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO.html) may help for how to set it up, most likely all you need is the ["I just want masquerading! Help!" chapter](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO-4.html#ss4.1)

Answer (score 0):

Or try here: http://www.randombugs.com/linux/install-vodafone-mobile-connect-linux.html

I think is possible to be exactly what you want. Usually this modems are exactly like a normal modem, and they connect on serial over USB.

Regards

Comment: That's what I did to configure my modem in Linux. I have it working already, but now I want to share this internet connection to another PC :)

Thank you

Comment: enable forwarding and iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -i eth0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to share to one other PC (for example, from wireless to cable) and you're using Ubuntu there's a [native option for that](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-easily-share-your-wireless-connection-in-ubuntu-9-10/).