# Serving internet with laptop via cable

Tags: linux, router, ethernet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Share internet in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/162172/share-internet-in-linux)

I have a linux laptop, connected to internet via wifi. I would like it to serve out the connection via its Ethernet port, so that another machine could access the internet via cable. What would be the best setup to do that?

Comment: You should consider giving us the OS of your laptop :)

Answer (score 2):

> What would be the best setup to do that?

Based on the information you've given, the answer is the setup you've already got. You just need to enable routing. There's lots of description of how to enable this on the internet. Try Google. [Here's a simple example](http://linuxpoison.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-configure-linux-as-internet.html) using masquerading. But there's other ways to allow access (application level proxying, conventional routing).

Comment: Why the mod-down? The resource symcbean links to is an excellent explanation.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but good answers should be self contained - that way, if something happens to the source, we should still be able to find an answer.