# Debian 6 Internet connection sharing aka IP masquerade not working

Tags: linux, debian, debian-squeeze, connection-sharing, dnsmasq

***The problem:*** the computers [Xbox 360 and a Kubuntu 12.04.1 laptop] can't access Internet through a recently-installed desktopless Debian 6 laptop (which is wirelessly connected to a WLAN station) but addresses are successfully given by `dnsmasq`.

***The attempts:***

**1.1)** `/etc/dnsmaq.conf` conffed according to http://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/dnsmasq: add lines

```
interface=eth0
dhcp-range=192.168.0.50,192.168.0.150,255.255.255.0,12h
```

**1.2)** Follow http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-fedora-linux-internet-connection-sharing-howto/ and use [their script](http://www.cyberciti.biz/files/scripts/linux-network-sharing-script.sh.txt) to setup iptables.

**2)** Follow the *Ubuntu Internet Gateway Method (iptables)* at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing recommended and which worked at [Share internet in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/162172/share-internet-in-linux).

The Debian laptop was rebooted many times and between each attempt, with and without [the script](http://www.cyberciti.biz/files/scripts/linux-network-sharing-script.sh.txt) auto-executing via `/etc/rc.local`.

While adding the `iptables-restore` command to that file I disabled the script.

**EDIT 1:**

Gateway is pingable and averages 39ms.

`iptables -nvL` with attempt #2 in effect, direct writing from the laptop's monitor after executing:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 179 packets, 26088 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source                  destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source                  destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  wlan0  eth0    192.168.0.0/24          0.0.0.0/0
         ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0               0.0.0.0/0
         ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 88 packets, 10716 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source                  destination
```

**EDIT 2:** `iptables -t nat -nvL`:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 232 packets, 56438 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source                  destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 60 packets, 4059 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source                  destination

    4  1032 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0               0.0.0.0/0


Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 64 packets, 5091 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source                  destination
```

**EDIT 3:** I tried https://www.debian-administration.org/articles/23 by telling /etc/rc.local to run it, and it alone, but still exactly same problem. This time I switched eth1 with wlan0.

Comment: Please show your actual ruleset (output of `iptables -nvL`).

Comment: Can they ping the gateway?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Yes the gateway is pingable.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Added to post.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers this prints the regular tables, not the NAT tables. @Rautamiekka, please provide the output of ``iptables -t nat -nvL``.

Comment: @gertvdijk: Added to post.

Comment: @Rautamiekka: What is your WAN interface and what is your LAN interface? Your current configuration is to masquerade for ``eth0``, but also provide a LAN on ``eth0``, which makes me believe you didn't configure the right interface for either your local or WAN (``wlan0``?) interface.

Comment: @gertvdijk: wlan0 is the WAN and eth0 is the LAN. So the interfaces are mixed up ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've set the wrong interface to perform `MASQUERADE` for. You state you want to 'share' the internet connection of the laptop provided by a wireless connection (probably `wlan0` on your machine) to a wired connection (seems to be `eth0` on your machine). However, your `POSTROUTING` chain rule is configured for `eth0` instead of `wlan0` (thev value in the `out` column is relevant here).

Try changing the script you mention to read like this:

```
# set wan interface such as eth1 or ppp0
SHARE_IF="wlan0"
```

It then uses that interface to set your iptabels rule correctly in these lines:

```
echo "Setting ${SHARE_IF} as router interface..."
$IPT --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface ${SHARE_IF} -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Replied to your comment on the OP.

Comment: @Rautamiekka: and I've just extended my answer to point you to the line in your script that I think should be checked and changed.

Comment: You know a bit more than me, so which of those attempted instructions are more worky ? By this answer you seem to favor the first one. Indeed, I failed with setting the WAN interface in the script.

Comment: @Rautamiekka: Which attempted instructions do you mean? I think I suggest exactly one: "Try..."

Comment: You're pointing at the 1.2.

Comment: Did this: change the SHARE_IF -> ran the script -> pinged gateway and averaged 0.353 -> pinged google.com and couldn't connect -> disconnected Kubu & Deb -> rebooted Deb -> connected Deb and then Kubu -> pinged google.com again and tried Internet with Firefox but still no connection. http://jodies.de/ipcalc says 0.0.0.0/0 has illegal value for subnet, could that be the problem ?

Comment: Fix: ... says 0.0.0.0/0 found in iptables' rules ...

Comment: Sorry, but no more ideas, you or someone else ?